# catching an IOError in python

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, ioerror

I wrote a method that does some stuff and catches bad filenames. what should happen is if the path doesn't exist, it throws an IOError. however, it thinks my exception handling is bad syntax... why??

```
def whatever():
    try:
        # do stuff
        # and more stuff
    except IOError:
        # do this
        pass
whatever()
```

but before it even gets to calling `whatever()`, it prints the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "getquizzed.py", line 55
    except IOError:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

when imported...help?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your indenting. This unhelpful `SyntaxError` error has <strike>[fooled me before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799974/continue-on-except-of-a-try-block-in-python)</strike> :)

From the deleted question:

```
I'd expect this to be a duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

Here's Python code, expected outcome of which should be obvious:

x = {1: False, 2: True} # no 3

for v in [1,2,3]:
  try:
      print x[v]
  except Exception, e:
      print e
      continue
I get the following exception: SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop.

I'd like to know how to avoid this error, which doesn't seem to be 
explained by the continue documentation.

I'm using Python 2.5.4 and 2.6.1 on Mac OS X, in Django.

Thank you for reading
```

Comment: @tekknalogi: How do you know it won't? What error message are you getting?

Comment: Unfortunately, the link does not exist any more. Care to explain what the problem was?

Answer (score 5):

there's 1 more possible if you're privileged to have an older installation

***and***

you're using the 'as' syntax:

`except IOError as ioe:`

***and***

the parser's getting tripped up on 'as'.

Using `as` is the preferred syntax in Python 2.6 and better.

It's a syntax error in Python 2.5 and older.  For pre-2.6, use this:

`except IOError, ioe:`

Answer (score 2):

Just missing something in your `try` block, i.e. `pass` or anything, otherwise it gives an indentation error.

Answer (score 1):

You will get a syntax error if you don't put something in side the `try` block.
You can put `pass` just to hold the space:

```
try:
    # do stuff
    # and more stuff
    pass
except IOError:
    # do this
    pass
```

Comment: oh there was stuff...see the comment. and why is your syntax highlighted not mine?

Comment: @tekknolagi try this insertion in first line of the code block: 
 <!-- language: lang-js -->